# Using substring and append in PHP SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I know this is going to sound kind of stupid but I Im trying to take the string "**MBLM108**0EUR**GF99**" and select "**MBLM108**" and also "**GF99**" and create a string without selecting the middle "0EUR" in a sub string and run it through a query as an or statement. The query works fine with just searching the first 7 characters but cant get it to OR search using the 11 characters without the middle ones.

This is the query without the or and it works fine:

```
 mysql_query("SELECT t.*, b.*, SUM(b.qty) AS qty FROM $table AS t JOIN bucket_part_bom AS b ON b.parent_part_num = SUBSTR(t.part_num, 1, 7) GROUP BY b.parent_part_num");
```

I'm just not sure how to accomplish selecting all but the middle 4 characters and make a string out of them and run it as an or statement in my query so it would search:

```
OR (SUBSTR(t.part_num, 1, 7).=SUBSTR(t.part_num, 11, 15))
```

just not sure how to write it

Answer (score 0):

You can use concat along with substr

```
 OR b.parent_part_num=
 Concat(SUBSTR(t.part_num, 1, 7),   SUBSTR(t.part_num, 11, 15))
```